# Phrasing a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Is there a more elegant way of saying this?

> He was a mathematician of the time when everyone else was illiterate in his home.

Comment: Questions that are primarily opinion-based or asking for writing advice are off-topic here, unless a problem is specifically identified. See [*What topics can I ask about here?*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 1):

"In a time" might sound better and in fact, I think it might even be more correct in this case.

And I would change the placement of "in his home" and also change it to say "in his household" or "at home".

> He was a mathematician in a time when everyone else in his household was illiterate.
>
> He was a mathematician in a time when everyone else at home was illiterate.

Comment: But I'm not sure what literacy has to do with being a mathematician here; I would not assume the two to be mutually exclusive. You could say "in a time when everyone else in his household had barely had any schooling."